# Filters for FFT signals for analysis and MFCC

Tags: signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis, mfcc

Below is the code I have been writing to try to create a mel triangular filter bank.

I start with 300 to 8000 hz range, convert the frequency to mels, and then mels back into frequency to then get the fft_bin numbers.

```
clear all;

g=[300 8000]; % low freqncy and fs/2 for the highest frequency

freq2mel=1125*log(1+(g/700)); % creating mel scale from the frequency
                                % answer  [401.25 2834.99]

f=linspace(0,2835,12); % if we want 10 filter banks that we use the
                         two endpoints and it will put 10 banks between them

                       % answer is [401.25 622.50 843.75 1065.0 1286.25 1507.50 1728.74 
                                     1949.99 2171.24 2392.49 2613.74 2834.99]

mel2freq=700*(exp(f/1125)-1); % converting the mel back into frequency

                               %answer is [300 517.33 781.90 1103.97 1496.04 1973.32 2554.33 
                                            3261.62 4122.63 5170.76 6446.70 8000]

fft_bins=floor((mel2freq/16000)*512); % creating fft bins

                                 %answer is [9 16 25 35 47 63 81 104 132 165 206 256]
```

My issue is this. I am stuck after this. I keep seeing the below filter bank piecewise function come up but I do not understand what K is in this function. Is k the array of $$ \mid(FFT)\mid ^2 $$ numbers from the hamming window? how to get the actual filter with the triangular output with magnitude of 1 to pass the $\mid(FFT)\mid^2$ to get my MFCC's. Can someone please help me out.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you do this kind of filtering, you have your spectrum in a 1D array and then you have a Mel filter bank in 2D matrix, with one dimension matching the FFT bins on your spectrum array, and another dimension being your target Mel bands. You multiply them and get your 1D Mel spectrum.

The `H_m` function really just describes a triangle centered around `m`, where `m` is the center Mel band and `k` is the frequency from 0 to Fs/2.  In theory, the `k` parameter should be continuous. You can assume that `k` is a FFT bin and it will kind of work, but you will not get great results at low frequencies where you entire Mel band covers 1 or 2 FFT bins. If you need to get a better resolution than that, you will consider how much of the triangle a particular FFT bin contains.